# UbuntuOne Control Panel can't change login

Tags: ubuntu-one, login

Where is the config file for the Ubuntu One Control Panel.. cant seem to locate it,and I need to change the account details...  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't [change the details from the Control Panel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/ControlPanel#Account),
you have to [completely remove and reinstall the Ubuntu One client](https://answers.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+faq/778).